# BIRT hide rows based on values in other dataset

Tags: javascript, loops, dataset, hide, birt

I am trying to do the following in BIRT:

I have a dataset with preferences of a user. For instance a preference might be: show all posts with type A, B and C. So the preferences dataset looks like this:

```
column_type
-----------
A
B
C
```

Then I have another dataset with all available posts like

```
ID    Name    type
-------------------
01    post1   A
02    post2   D
03    post3   C
04    post4   A
```

Now I want to show only the posts with A, B and C (B will not show cause there are no posts with typeB)

Therefore I hide the row with the following code:

hide if
(dataset, preferences)row._outer["type"] != (dataset, posts)row["type"]

```
ID    Name    type
-------------------
01    post1   A
```

I only get the first row. It doesn't loop through the rest of the dataset. Does have anybody got an idea how to loop through the rest of the dataset?

Any help would be appreciated,

Kind regards,

Michel

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you just want to join the data sets on the *type* column, am I correct?

If you're using the BIRT designer you can do that by going to the data explorer and right-click on Data Sets -> New Joint Data Set, this opens a new dialog where you can select the data sets, the join type and the column to join.